# Find all possible Euler cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have implemented an algorithm to find an Euler cycle for a given starting vertex in an undirected graph (using DFS and removing visited edges), but it always returns only one path. How do I modify the algorithm to search for all possible Euler cycles for a vertex?

Here is relevant code:

```
typedef int Graph[200][200]; // adjacency matrix
int v, e; // vertex count, edge count

......

void DFS(Graph &G, int x) {
    int i;
    Push(x);
    for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
        if (G[i][x] > 0) {
            G[i][x] = 0;
            G[x][i] = 0;
            DFS(G, i);
            break;
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you post your implementation? It shouldn't require too many changes.

Comment: You didn't test for bridges? This isn't a euler circuit!? Or is there a difference between euler circuit and euler cycle?

Comment: Yes, no bridge detection for now. Just trying to make it work on simple graphs first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the recursive call, you should reinsert the edges you deleted before, and get rid of the break.

```
void DFS(Graph &G, int x) 
{
    int i;
    Push(x);
    for (i = 0; i < v; i++)
        if (G[i][x] > 0) 
        {
            G[i][x] *= -1;
            G[x][i] *= -1;
            DFS(G, i);
            G[i][x] *= -1;
            G[x][i] *= -1;
        }

}
```

All you need now is a way to figure out when you've generated a full cycle so you can print it and move on to the next. That happens when you've eliminated every edge of your graph.

Comment: Hum, it seems to produce all possible cycles, not just Euler ones. But it's very helpful anyway. It is very easy to select Euler cycles from these, and I think this is exactly what was expected from me in this problem.

Answer (score -2):

You want to loop through all vertex.

Comment: Why downvote? Isn't that a serious answer? He can try all combinations?

Comment: There can be multiple cycles starting from one vertex and looping though all verteces doesn't solve this. Downvote wasn't mine btw.