# Euler paths DFS implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I'm implementing an algorithm to find all the euler paths in a graph. I'm basing myself, to create the dfs, in the code found here: [Find all possible Euler cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023137/find-all-possible-euler-cycles)

Here is my current code:

```
public class Graph {

private int numVertex;
private int numEdges;
private boolean[][] adj;

public Graph(int numVertex, int numEdges) {
    this.numVertex = numVertex;
    this.numEdges = numEdges;
    this.adj = new boolean[numVertex+1][numVertex+1];
}

public void addEdge(int start, int end){
    adj[start][end] = true;
    adj[end][start] = true;
}

public Integer DFS(Graph G, int startVertex){
    int i=0;
    pilha.push(startVertex);
    for(i=0; i<G.numVertex; i++){

        if(G.adj[i][startVertex] != false){
            System.out.println("i: " + i);
            G.adj[i][startVertex] = false;
            G.adj[startVertex][i] = false;

            DFS(G, i);

            G.adj[i][startVertex] = true;
            G.adj[startVertex][i] = true;
        }

    }
    return -1;
}

Stack<Integer> pilha = new Stack();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numVertices = input.nextInt();
    int numLinks = input.nextInt();
    int startNode = input.nextInt();

    Graph g = new Graph(numVertices, numLinks);

    for(int i = 0; i<numLinks; i++){
        g.addEdge(input.nextInt(),input.nextInt());
    }

}
```

}

Unfortunately i don't get the right results and i can't seem to figure out why. I've tried a lot of thing as storing the results from the dfs in a list and print them, but still i got no paths.

any idea on how can i modify my code so i start getting the euler paths?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the result from your program to be? You are pushing the nodes to a temporary stack(pilha). You need to keep that stack because it will in fact determine the order in which you should visit the nodes. Also the DFS method is void but somehow you add the result from its invocation in the list res. Does this code even run successfully?

Comment: Sorry, the code was a bit clunky when i added it. I will try to clean it up a bit.

Comment: It is still not clear. With the new change there is no reason to have DFS returning an integer. Also use pilha somehow.

Comment: I will probably need to have dfs running with the stack so i can backtrack it. But as it is right now, i can perform DFS search in a graph.